# angular file upload validation

Tags: angular, validation

I am trying to validate file upload field. first i try to required field validation. but its now working
please check my code

```
<input type="file" accept=".pdf" (change)="readUrl()" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f.touched && cvFile.invalid}" name="cvFile" #cvFile="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="signupModel.cvFile"  required/>
   <div *ngIf="cvFile.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="cvFile.errors.required">CV is required</div>
        </div>
```

this required validation not working. if you know please help to validate 
upload only max size also.
Thanks you

Comment: A couple things aren't right. For one, your accept should be `accept="application/pdf"`

Comment: yes i know it. but user can select 'selecting all files'. therefore this solution not good

Comment: Could you change the ngIf to `*ngIf="cvFile.hasError('required')"`

Comment: i checked. but required error messages did not appear